# React native text is cutting when render

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, text

I'm making an app in react native, this work fine in the majority devices, but in Honor and some Samsungs devices the text is cutting suddenly.

**How i rendered my text?**

I attach an example how to make this:

in Src/localization/global_es.json

```
{
"closeSegment": "Concluir segmento",
}
```

and in my component:

```
 <BtnGradient
     onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
     colorText={'black'}
     title={t('segmentScreen.closeSegment')}
/>
```

where

```
const BtnGradient = ({
    onPress,
    colorText,
    title,
    disabled,
    widthValue = 0.95,
}: BtnProps) => {
    const auth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            disabled={disabled}
            onPress={onPress}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>
            <Container widthValue={widthValue}>
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={[
                        auth.user.company.secondaryColor,
                        auth.user.company.mainColor,
                    ]}
                    style={{
                        width: SCREEN_WIDTH * widthValue,
                        height: normalize(40),
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        borderRadius: normalize(10),
                        padding: 10,
                    }}>
                    <Title color={colorText}>{title}</Title>
                </LinearGradient>
            </Container>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

export default BtnGradient;

const Container = styled.View<{background: string}>`
    width: ${(props: {widthValue: number}) =>
        SCREEN_WIDTH * props.widthValue}px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: ${normalize(10)}px;
    margin: ${normalize(5)}px;
    //box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
`;
const Title = styled.Text<{color: string}>`
    color: ${(props: {color: string}) => props.color};
    font-size: ${normalize(16)}px;
`;
```

**Hoped result:**
Render all text "Concluir segmento"

**obtained result:** [image]

Libs:
"react-i18next": "^13.5.0",
"i18next": "^23.7.9",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-i18next": "^13.5.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",

Answer (score 0):

This may related to Android device default `fontWeight` setting. Some user will set the default font as bold. If your code doesn't specify any `fontWeight` property in text, some text may cut-off.
[Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114) is raised on 2017 but it still happening.

To solve this, add `fontWeight: 'bold'` in your text style should fix the issue.